# Cannot boot my system, stuck at Windows 7 updates

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, windows-update, system-restore, shutdown

I have a HP ProBook 4520s, I have installed Windows 7. I updated it from internet and on system shutdown, it said,

> Please do no power off or unplug you machine , Installing update 36 of 47.

And eventually, after charging ended, my machine was turned off. Then, whenever I power on this machine it is stuck at same place. I have looked online for this problem, but many people say to put in the Windows DVD, or starting in safe mode.

My question is: How? When I tried to shut down the system it just goes to standby or hibernate I guess. The power button slightly blinks. When I start it again it is exactly at same situation.

So I am totally stuck at this place. Is there any way to get my system out of this situation? I will be even happy to remove Windows, re-install it, or even install Linux. But I have some work to do on system that is urgent. But want to get out of this situation. So what can I do, short of replacing the hard drive?

Comment: Just my 2 pence worth, if you can't work out how to power down a laptop I'd avoid Linux

Comment: I already used linux for almost a year, I am a web developer,  but you know microsoft technology, unpredictable ;)

Comment: Pull out the battery and unplug the AC adapter. Then plug the AC adapter and power up the laptop again. It should boot normally. Tell us if it gets stuck at the update part again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the power button for about 7-10 seconds. This will power off the machine.

Comment: this don't power off it but it goes to standby/hibernate . And when I start again , it is at same place. I already tried all this.

Comment: Have you held the power button down for 10 seconds? Or just pressed it? A probook 4520 will completely power down if you hold the power button in but will go to sleep / hibernate if you just press the power button

Comment: ah, I was pressing it for almost 5-6 seconds and thought that it was off, but thanks for mentioning 10 seconds as it really off exactly after 10 seconds. So HP don't give full control to OS. My mistake in thinking wrong way.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps. Most computers have this feature built in to thier physical construction, helps when all else fails.

Comment: The "Hold power button to shut-off completely" feature is a standard BIOS feature to be used as a last resort when OS is not shutting down properly. It's there in all computers with soft-power-buttons (power buttons that inform OS that they have been pressed). If holding doesn't work, the _true_ last resort to simply remove all power sources (battery, AC adapter).